# How can I use log in Java, just like console.log() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, typescript

how can I use a `log()` on Java, the way we use `console.log()` in javascript?

It gives me a syntax error

Please and thank you, best regards

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same thing.

Comment: console.log does not exist in java. are you trying to write a java or java script program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.out.print("Hello word")` in order to print on your console.

If you want to learn more https://www.javatpoint.com/system-out-println-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't use console.log; it is a totally different language than Javascript.  You would use `System.out.print` or `System.out.println` instead.

Good luck with your learning!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to take a **tutorial** anyway:

```
System.out.println(String msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println("message");` will write a message to the console.